# Generate excel (.xlsx) for categorization of database/content

Tags: excel, ms-office, categories

Problem:
I have a folder name 'XYZ' (saved at D:\PQRS\2022), which comprises two more folders named 'January' and 'March'. Folder 'January' comprises multiple types of files. It also comprises three office (.doc or .docx) files. Each file comprises text 'message type : ', for example file 1 contains 'message type: Apple', file 2 contains 'message type: Banana' and file 3 contains 'message type: Apple'. The folder named 'March' has 2 files. File 1 comprises 'message type: Banana' and file 2 contains 'message type: '.

I want to generate an excel file named 'XYZ'which comprises the following information
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no clue which tool should I use?